# Как recv() понимает, что все данные получены в случаи TCP?

Tags: c++, c, сокет, tcp

Насколько я понимаю, данные через TCP передаются как сплошной поток, до тех пор пока соединение не будет разорвано. Если посмотреть на структуру сегмента TCP,там даже нет информации о длинне данных (в отличии от UDP, к примеру).
Таким образом, если мы читаем что-то с TCP сокета в буфер, чтение будет происходить до тех пор, пока соединение не закроется, либо буффер не переполниться.

Однако если посмотреть на реальный код, это не так - recv() на сервере читает ровно столько байт, сколько отправлено с клиента с помощью send()

Каким образом recv() понимает, что все данные получены, и управление нужно вернуть в вызывающий код?

Полный и минимальный пример на голых сокетах:

Сервер:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <memory>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
const int PORT = 12345;

int main() {
    //create server socket
    int socketFd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socketFd < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    int opt_val = 1;
    setsockopt(socketFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt_val, sizeof opt_val);


    //bind to address
    sockaddr_in socketAddress;
    socketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socketAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    socketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    int rc = ::bind(socketFd,
                    reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&socketAddress),
                    sizeof(socketAddress));
    if (rc < 0) {
        return -2;
    }


    //listen
    rc = ::listen(socketFd, SOMAXCONN);
    if (rc < 0) {
        return -3;
    }

    //accept new connection
    sockaddr_in socketAdress;
    unsigned int sizeOfSocketAdress = sizeof(socketAdress);
    int clientSocket = ::accept(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *)&socketAdress, &sizeOfSocketAdress);
    if (clientSocket < 0) {
        return -4;
    }

    //receive
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int receivedBytes = ::recv(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, MSG_NOSIGNAL);

    std::cout << "Received " << receivedBytes << " bytes : "  << buffer << std::endl; // Прочитано 5 байт "hello", хотя буфер не заполнен и соединение не прервано
    return 0;
}
```

Клиент:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    int res;
    int socketFd;

    socketFd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (socketFd == -1) {
      perror("cannot create socket");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);

    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = htons(12345);
    res = inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &sa.sin_addr);

    if (connect(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa) == -1) {
      perror("connect failed");
      close(socketFd);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    auto buf = "hello";
    auto len = 5;

    int sentBytes = ::send(socketFd, buf, len, 0);

    std::cout << "sent " << sentBytes << "bytes: " << buf << std::endl;

    std::string tmp;
    std::getline(std::cin, tmp); //приостановка выполнения, соединение все еще не закрыто
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Ваш recv читает ровно нужное кол-во данных только по одной причине - данных бегает немного и они на локалхосте. Сделайте две разные машины, желательно в разных сетях и все сразу станет веслее

Comment: @KoVadim и что будет в разных сетях?

Comment: recv будет читать сколько, сколько у него получилось (конечно, не больше запрошенного). И вполне реальная ситуация, когда с одной стороны отправляют большими кусками данные, а с другой вначале читается один байт. А потом уже сколько попросишь.

Comment: @KoVadim, а) это да, извините я подумал про другое) именно поэтому читают как правило циклами

Answer (score 2):

Нет, `recv` читает количество байт *не больше* указанного размера буфера, совершенно не волнуясь по поводу получения всех данных. В лучшем случае с клиента приходит пакет с флагом PSH, намекающий, что имеет смысл отдать данные читателю сейчас.

Comment: Хорошо, мое заблуждение. Но ответ на вопрос "Каким образом recv() понимает, что все данные получены, и управление нужно вернуть в вызывающий код?" хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: @NikBond Никаким образом не понимает.

Comment: Хорошо, т.е. вызов send() на клиенте после передачи сегмента с данными посылает сегмент в флагом PSH, а recv() на сервере заканчивает чтение после получения этого сегмента? 
Смущает формулировка "в лучшем случае" и "намекающий"
Если сегмент с PSH не придет, чтение будет и дальше до заполнения буфера?

Comment: @NikBond Данные могут копиться в буфере даже если PSH придет неоднократно.

Comment: т.е. поведение recv() непредсказуемо? Он может вернуть буфер в момент когда отправленное с клиента  сообщение получено не полностью, когда в буфер записаны два отправленных подряд с клиента сообщения, может ждать до посинения пока не заполниться буфер даже если все отправленные сообщения пришли? 
Соответственно, применение голого ТСП без более высокоуровненого протокола который контроллирует длинну сообщения бессмысленно?

Comment: @NikBond Совершенно верно.

Answer (score 1):

> Каким образом recv() понимает, что все данные получены, и управление
>   нужно вернуть в вызывающий код?

Никаким. Это забота приложения. С точки зрения приложения, TCP канал - это обычный файл.  Как приложение узнаёт, что некая порция данных принята полностью? Существует только два способа:

1. Есть определённый символ - разделитель записей. Для большинства текстовых файлов, этот символ - '\n'
2. В начале порции данных пишется длина блока. Как конкретно это делается - зависит от конкретного приложения.

Оба эти пункта 100% применимы к ТСР соединениям. Например, в HTTP протоколе применяется вариант пункта 1: каждое сообщение НАЧИНАЕТСЯ специальной строкой заголовка и ЗАВЕРШАЕТСЯ пустой строкой. Данные передаются несколько иным способом, но идея та же.

Answer (score 0):

Поведение TCP непредсказуемо :) нет никакой 100% гарантии что 'пакет пользовательских данных' доставлен частично или полностью. Это вам решать в своей программе.
Имеет смысл иногда проводить доп проверки на наличие данных, покажу на примере функции вычитывающей все данные для  `асинхронного сокета`:

```
// функция работает как 'умный' TCP.socket.data.flush

void tcp_recv_empty(int sock, ssize_t sz)
{
    ssize_t       rsz;
    unsigned char rbuf[65536]; // 1500 более бережно :)

#   if !defined(MSG_WAITALL)
#   define MSG_WAITALL 0x40
#   endif

    if (!sz)
    {
        if ((ioctl(sock, FIONREAD, &sz) != 0) || (!sz)) { return; }
    }
    while (sz > 0)
    {
        errno = 0;
        switch ((rsz = recv(sock, rbuf, sizeof(rbuf), MSG_WAITALL)))
        {
            case (ssize_t)-1:
            {
#               if defined(EAGAIN)
                if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EINTR))
#               elif defined(EWOULDBLOCK)
                if ((errno == EWOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EINTR))
#               endif
                {
                    continue;
                }
                return;
            }
            case 0:
            {
                return;
            }
            default:
            {
                sz -= rsz;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Всегда надо полагаться на код возврата `recv*()` и состояние получаемое например такой функцией:

```
int net_socket_iserror(int sock)
{
    int se;
    socklen_t sl = sizeof(int);

#   if defined(SO_ERROR)
    if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &se, &sl) < 0)
    {
        return errno;
    }
    return se;
#   else
    return 0;
#   endif
}
```

Comment: Tcp как раз и предназначег для гарантии доставки, в отличие от UDP. Или что вы имеете ввиду: что у сетевой платы пропадет питание, радиоволна растворится в мировом пространстве..etc?

Comment: Там же вроде для асинхронных сокетов через select или poll работа шла, вы в этом контексте вызывать будете ? После select ?

Comment: Ключевое слово `пакет пользовательских данных`, передающая сторона в любой момент может прервать передачу данных по разным объективным причинам, протокол TCP никак не гарантирует передачу `всех` данных с точки зрения программы их обрабатывающей. Автор сам должен проверять все ли данные пришли или это часть переданных данных. Про `select  vs poll vs epoll` комментарий непонятен, он не имеет прямого отношение к состоянию сокета после recv и проверки ошибок, уровень селектора стоит несколько выше, и по результатам обработки им вызываются send/recv/shutdown/close.

Comment: протокол tcp гарантирует доставку данных (будете ли вы читать эти данные или нет, это уже ваше дело и протокол тут не при чем). Также непонятно в чем асинхронность вашей функции, если она ставится в блок вызовом recv(... MSG_WAITALL) ? Вопрос про poll следующий: чтобы отслеживать изменения состояния сокетов используются функции select/poll. Если select/poll вернул вам POLLIN/POLLOUT - значит уже можно без блокировки читать/писать из сокета, что делать с вашей функцией? И почему состояние сокета не измениться после recv?

Comment: tcp не гарантирует доставку. Это очень распространенное заблуждение. Пруф - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793 9 страница, 2 абзац.

Comment: @KoVadim, вы что-то подрываете устои интернета... тсп все же гарантирует доставку, что имеется в иду в рфц под словами "end user" я хз. ACK означает, что все пакеты от SEQ+1 до ACK-1 были успешно получены, или мы говорим о разных гарантиях)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, эта функция реализует флеш принятых данных и приводится как пример что бы показать применение `ioctl(.., FIONREAD, &..)`. На самом деле, применение ее разумно на клиентах которые по той или иной причине льют что-то ненужное потоком, дабы освободить буфер и в последствии отправить клиенту ответ. К таким клиентам относиться кстати AJAX :)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, вы пропускаете самую суть формулировки: `Ключевое слово пакет пользовательских данных` - это не TCP пакет :)

Comment: @NewView, теперь понятно где собака, назвали бы посылкой данных, а то пакет вводит в заблуждение)

Comment: @goldstar_labs да, я умею их подрывать. Если бы тсп гаратировал доставку, то вытянутый сетевой шнурок или клетка фарадея не были бы ему преградой.